# django freetds pyodbc error at inserting russian letters

Tags: sql-server, django, encoding, pyodbc, freetds

I have my app in Django in Linux. And MS SQL Database on Windows. They're  connected by pyodbc\freetds drivers. English data is inserted good. And i can see it in db, but **russian characters cause error:**

Code:

```
p = Person()
# also tried u'Вася', unicode('Вася'), 'Вася'.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1251')
p.name='Вася'
p.save()
```

Error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000','[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The incoming tabular
data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The stream ended unexpectedly.
(4002) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I've set in odbc.ini and freetds.conf:

```
tds_version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

P.s. Also "Select * from mytable" returns ????? instead of russian chars.

Comment: There's a lot of good discussion here (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.tds.freetds/10294) about a problem that seems similar to yours. Can you post the code for your insert statement (including parameter binding)?

Comment: p=Person() p.name='Вася' #also tried u'Вася', unicode('Вася'), 'Вася'.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1251'). then p.save() --> error